# Ajax - checking if multiple URLs are valid

Tags: jquery, ajax, async-await

I have 2 URLs. I first want to check if URL1 is valid, if so, then I want to return URL1, otherwise if its not valid, I want to check if URL2 is valid, and if so, return URL2, if neither are valid, then return null:

```
if (check(url1))
    return url1;
else if (check(url2))
    return url2;
else return null;
```

How do I accomplish this with Ajax, asynronously? I'm struggling to see how I would get the checking of Url2 to occur if url1 has failed. This is what I have so far, but its probably totally wrong:

```
function check(url) {
    $.ajax({type: 'HEAD', url: url,
    success: function() { return url; },
    error: function() { return `${url} not found`; }});
}

async function checkUrl(url1, url2) {
    try {
        return await check(url1);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        try {
            return await check(url2);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when it's async, the second url check will start at the same time with the first url. do you want this or do you want sync (wait until first is completed)?

Comment: No, I only want the 2nd URL check to occur if the 1st URL check fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `done` and `error` events of $.ajax promise and return a new promise:

```
function getImages(url1, url2){
    var dfr = new $.Deferred();  // will hold the promise
    $.ajax({
         type: 'HEAD', 
         url: url1               // first check url1
    }).done(function(result, status, XHR){ 
       alert('success:'+XHR.status);           // if it succeeds
       dfr.resolve(url1);        // resolve the promise with url1
    }).fail(function(){          // if it fails
        $.ajax({                 
           type: 'HEAD',
           url: url2             // then check url2
        }).done(function(result, status, XHR){ 
            alert('success:'+XHR.status);      // if it succeeds
            dfr.resolve(url2);   // resolve the promise with url2
        }).fail(function(){      // if it fails
            dfr.reject();        // reject the promise
        });
    });
    return dfr;                  // return the promise to process outside.
}
```

to use it:

```
getImages(url1, url2)             // call the method which will return a promise,
  .done(function(image){          // if it resolves
    // image will contain the existing image. url1 or url2.
    img.src = image;
}).fail(function(){               // if it rejects
    window.alert("Both images can't be loaded");
});
```

For more about Deferred/Promise, you can read this:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Comment: that's not working, URLs that I know don't return 200 are still hitting the `done` event, rather than the `fail` one.

Comment: you can filter out ajax response http status and resolve & reject which cases you want. This answer provides you the chaining ability.

Comment: How would I reject a 404 then? Where would I get that information?

Comment: 200 for every instance of URL1, even though my browser is saying 404.

Comment: are you running this on a server or locally?

Comment: on a server. But i'm using this: https://gist.github.com/dropmeaword/a050231a5767adc52b986faf587f64c9 to get round cors

Comment: can you try without that proxy to a same origin and a cross origin resource? if it gives correct results, might be an issue with that file. it may not support HEAD requests.